# How to receive array of object in Sveltekit Action?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm new to Sveltekit,

I have a form with the input names set like so:

```
input 1: config[0][name]
input 2: config[0][type]
input 3: config[1][name]
input 4: config[2][type]
```

here in the Sveltekit Action I tried to `console.log` it:

```
'config[0][name]': '',
'config[0][type]': '',
'config[1][name]': '',
'config[1][type]': '',
```

so because of that I can only access the data like this `formData['config[0][name]']`

here's my code:

```
 const create: Action = async ({request})=> {
    const formData = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());
    
    console.log("data", formData);
    }
```

how can I receive it as an array that I can access normally like this?

```
formData.config[0].name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge there is currently no built-in way and [a feature request for that](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1309) has been rejected.

The data essentially needs to be parsed based on this bracket notation which is just a common convention. There might be some existing libraries you could use or you can implement the logic yourself.

Comment: I see, thanks for highlighting it to me. previously I was working with PHP Laravel before changing to Sveltekit and it was working fine there, I thought this was something that every framework does. again thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
My array was called "packs"
This was the logic I added to get around it...

```
  for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
    if (key.startsWith("packs[")) {
      const match = key.match(/packs\[(\d+)\]\[(\w+)\]/);
      if (match) {
        const index = match[1];
        const property = match[2];
        if (!packs[index]) {
          packs[index] = {};
        }
        packs[index][property] = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

Therefore creating an array from name: "packs[0][numberOfItems]" which becomes [{numberOfItems: 1}] and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question. Here is how I've got it:

1. Have removed all square brackets from name attribute in my form inputs.
2. Have used formData.getAll() method to get all values of inputs with the same name (according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll).

Works pretty good to me.